# ios change constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am using autolayout with a constraint.
The top space to superview is 100

I now want to change this so that when the user rotates the device to landscape
The top space to superview is 50

Can this be done at design time?

How can this be done at runtime?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, if your `50` px for landscape and `100` for portrait can somehow be derived by relations to sibling subviews and fixed offsets to the bounds of superview, then yes, this can be done "at design time", and that's actually what auto layout is meant to be for.

Otherwise you would need to have a reference to the `constraint`, then in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method you need to change the value of the `constant` of this `constraint` and call `layoutIfNeeded` for the superview.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    self.myConstraint.constant = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) ? 50. : 100.;
    [self.someView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

(written in the browser, might have mistakes)

Comment: i just need to know how attribute value to a NSLayoutConstraint.
Thanks for your help NSLayoutConstraint.constant