# TableView and CollectionView in the same ViewController with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm building my application with Swift and I want to set up `TableView` and `CollectionView` in the same `ViewController`.

[image: It should look like this (image here)]

The only answer I founded is to setup my `CollectionView` in the `TableViewCell` of the `TableView`.

I did it but it scrolls separately.

The solution I found is to disable `CollectionView` scrolling and then configure `CollectionView`'s height constraint programmatically by summing heights of the cells. It isn't perfect at all because cells become non reusable (250+).

I'm in desperation because I have seen this setup in many other apps and I think that answer is so simple but I can not find it anywhere.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you a lot!

Comment: simply use (one or more) container views for this type of problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to set it up as a single collection view with two sections, one that looks and lays out as a tableview and the other that has the more collection view appearance.

Or set it up as a single table view with two sections, one of which displays two side-by-side images per line (this is the old school way of creating this layout.)

Lots of ways to go about it, depending on what you want to play with and what you want to learn :)

Comment: Two sections in one CollectionView sounds reasonable for me.. Can you please give me a link to a proper tutorial with this kind of set up? Specifically how to implement two sections in one CollectionView? Thank you!

Comment: The actual implementation is going to center around the `UICollectionViewDataSource` method `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and creating a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` which handles each section differently.  I'm not aware of any tutorials specific to the problem though.

Comment: Another possibility would be to create the table view as a header to the collection view and make sure that the header size is updated to the size of the tableview.

Comment: ok, thank you. I figure it out. The only question I have left is what I should write in the cellForItemAtIndexPath block? Because `if section == 0 { }` throws me an error that `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'section.Type' and 'Int'`

Comment: Not sure where you're getting section.  Using the auto expanded code, you should be using `if indexPath.section == 0 {...} else {}`

Comment: You are my saver! It worked great for me!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` inside a `UIViewController`, and implement `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDataSource`.

Keys:

1. Use `AutoLayout` to make sure tableView has only two rows, and
       collectionView takes the rest of area.
2. Make sure tableView.scrollEnabled = false

Here is a sample, https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6yc40udfk8mqx5/FlexTableCellHeight.zip?dl=0

Comment: The point is that TableView can have more then two rows, depends from the server response

Comment: In this case, you have to manually control tableView's height.  e.g. Add a outlet of tableView's constraint, and update the constraint according to tableView's rows.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542626/ios-change-constraint-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Set up a blank ViewController.  Then place two ContainmentViewControllers inside of the ViewController. Size them however you want based on how much screen you want to the be tableview and how much you want to be collectionview.  Then create segues from each containmentViewController to your tableviewcontroller and collectionviewcontroller using embed.  This will allow both to be on screen at once and scroll separately.

If you do not need to use a TableViewController and can get away with just a tableview you can also just place one containmentviewcontroller below your tableview and create the embed segue to your collectionviewcontroller.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't want them to scroll separately and that is my problem

Comment: i als have same issue i have collection at top and below that their is a tableview i want to scroll both at same time swift